# Webview in CEFSharp to render HTML content

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, cefsharp

My objective is to render the html content into text with its styles, indent and all others. I just done a workaround with [CEFSharp v1.25.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf/1.25.5) with the following code and it works like charm.

```
CefSharp.Wpf.WebView webView= new CefSharp.Wpf.WebView();
webView.LoadHtml("<p> this is <b>paragraph<b></p>");
```

Since I am developing a 64bit application,I'm not able to implement the same in my application. So, I found latest version of [CefSharp v37.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf/) with 64bit support. But the sad part is I could not find the 'WebView' here. I tried the following code without any luck.

```
CefSharp.Wpf.ChromimWebBrowser browser= new CefSharp.Wpf.ChromimWebBrowser();
browser.LoadHtml = ("<p> this is <b>paragraph<b></p>","dummy:");
```

I need to show the html webcontent in webview container in a 64bit target platform like the webview in Cefsharp v1.25.5.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there's a few things you should do, all covered in [CefSharp Troubleshooting](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting).

- Initialise CEF
- Add the browser to the Controls collection
- I prefer to LoadHtml in a method attached to the browser.IsInitialisedEvent (and only load when the event.IsBrowserInitialised is true)

Hope these help. If there are any other issue do let us know!